# Repeatedly getting Label warnings

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, texworks, ref

I am repeatedly getting label warnings in TeXWorks despite running the compilation twice or more. I can't find the problem that is causing this. The PDFLaTeX compiler referenced the section correctly but I still get the warnings. Why?

[image]
[image]

Comment: that is normal on the first run, just run latex again and cross references will resolve.

Comment: check if definition of the profile pdflatex+makeindex+bibtex contains a `--clean` option.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mentioned that I compiled more than twice.

Comment: I know but the image you show is clearly of a first run with no pre-existing aux file, and you provided no test file so the image is all we have,

Comment: I ran PDFLaTeX and MakeIndex separately. This removed the warnings.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer the definition has `--clean` in its argument.

Comment: remove it, it cleans up all the time and so remove the aux-file.

Comment: thanks, the combinations don't cause problems now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ulrike's comment: The compilation call contained the `--clean` option which deletes all auxiliary files after the compilation. This caused the `label` warning.